# How do we get handle of Rhapsody model (.rpy) opened from Matlab command window?

Tags: matlab, invoke-command, rhapsody

The first requirement is to invoke and open Rhapsody model through Matlab command window. That can be done using system or winopen commands. But I do not get any handle of the rhapsody model after it is opened. My second requirement is to save the rhapsody model using matlab command (and I believe for that the handle must be obtained from requirement 1)
Any leads on this will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the MATLAB COM ActiveX related functions to get a handle to Rhapsody in MATLAB.  Since Rhapsody is already running do the execution of the system or winopen command, the MATLAB command to connect to it and return a handle is:

rhapApp = actxGetRunningServer('Rhapsody.application');

Once rhapApp is returned, you can use the get, set, methods and invoke functions in MATLAB to get info on the handle item related to available attributes and functions.

Rhapsody has the peculiar behavior that there doesn't seem to be any way to make the GUI visible on the computer if the COM function 'actxserver' is used to start Rhapsody.  In othter words, you can use:

rhapApp = actxserver('Rhapsody.application')

to start Rhapsody and get a handle returned, but it will result in Rhapsody running the background and no way to view the model with the Rhapsody GUI simultaneously.

Once you have the handle to the Rhapsody app, you can use the API to open existing models or create new models.

You should be able to use the following command to save the model:

rhapProj.save